# SDKS workload folder missing for Visual Studio 22 Enterprise on Windows

Tags: .net, sdk, visual-studio-2022

I'm working on installing visual studio 2022 on a docker file.
The problem I 'm having is that the sdks folder is missing from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild so when I run a build pipeline with the docker container, I receive the following error message.

MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" because directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk" did not exist.

```
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_enterprise.exe --includeRecommended --quiet --nocache
--norestart --wait \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools --includeOptional \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data \
    --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.6.0 --includeOptional \
    --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.7.0 --includeOptional \
    --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK --includeOptional \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreBuildTools --includeOptional \
    --add Microsoft.Component.CodeAnalysis.SDK \ 
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.CodedUITest \   || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0
```

I'm cleary installing SDK in the image so I'm not sure what is missing? anyone has an idea?
[image]